# Browse back and forth by mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, agi

How can you make whether case 1 goes to the next result case 2 goes to the previous result
Thanks a lot (I'm still a little new, any help will be received)

```
<?php
$search = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `Products` ORDER BY `Products`.`abc_phone` ASC");
while($AnswerP = mysqli_fetch_array($search)){

   /*code...
   ...
   */

   $next = $agi->get_data($FolderToPlay."next_and_oder",7000,1)['result'];
   switch ($next){
    case 1:
      next...;
    break;
    case 2:
        previous...;
    break;
    case 3:
        oder();
    break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does "result" mean result-set you get from database? or you mean the case statement that executed

Comment: ta next get from database

Comment: Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: Can you give me an example in the code that I will understand the action ?

Comment: See below on that same page

Comment: Thank you ! But how do I know which line it is now to do plus and minus